# Vertically align thumbnail images to the top - CSS

Tags: html, css, image, gallery

Client is uploading thumbnail images of different heights and my image gallery seems to not be aligning things to the top.  I have been spinning my wheels for a while trying to find the issue.  Any help much appreciated.

Here's a link, you'll see how the taller images are not top-aligned the same as the smaller ones.  However, all the smaller images are aligning correctly.

http://scharf.geodesicgrafx.com/gallery/stock-photos-non-exclusive

Comment: they do allign the same way on hover event. so you should start fixing from there

Comment: i think the best way to organise the layout would be by vertical align center. then the list will look more proper maybe

Comment: thanks a lot for the suggestions.   yes, they do align on hover.  maybe the hover requires this strange alignment so that it can, in fact, enlarge. i tried adding vertical align (though i do need it to be top and not center) but never found the right place where it worked.

Comment: maybe i should just remove the hover effect if thats the case since the client wants it top-aligned

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for that

```css
.image-container{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 2px solid #a29e9e;
    border-radius: 2px;
    overflow: hidden;
  }
img{
  width:100%;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: all 2s;
}
img:hover{
  width:200%;
  margin-left:-70px;
  margin-top:-90px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="image-container">
<img src="http://scharf.geodesicgrafx.com/images/dmImage/SourceImage/197405-1-6Ca-Spider-Mite1.jpg">
</div>
```

You can use this trick, 
Adjust the width and height of the div(image-container) as your need.
Images upload by the user must come inside the image container div.
The image must be 100% in width(style).

OR

If you wish to show the sample of whole pic just use this style sheet. remove overflow property of the div and gave height to the image (height of the container itself)

```
.image-container{
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 2px solid #a29e9e;
    border-radius: 2px;
  }
img{
  width:100%;
    -webkit-transition: width 2s; /* For Safari 3.1 to 6.0 */
    transition: all 2s;
  height:200px;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, Aswin.  I will give this a shot and report back!